# Getting createContainerConfigError when running pod; Error: stat /path/to/pv: no such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

I've been digging into persistent volumes and I've run into this problem.

I created a persistent volume on one of my directories to store things such as database data, initialization scripts, config files, etc... for my postgres deployment. Here is the postgres-pvc-pv.yaml:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-volume  # Sets PV's name
  labels:
    #Stype: local  # Sets PV's type to local
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi # Sets PV Volume
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/home/kubernetesUser/postgresKubernetes/volume"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim  # Sets name of PVC
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany  # Sets read and write access
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi  # Sets volume size
  volumeName: postgres-pv-volume
```

As you can see the volume is in the path `/home/kubernetesUser/postgresKubernetes/volume`

And here is the deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:alpine 
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432  
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
            - secretRef:
                  name: postgres-secret
          volumeMounts:
#            - name: postgres-data
#              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
#              subPath: data
#            - name: postgres-data
#              mountPath: /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
#              subPath: my-postgres.conf
            - name: postgres-data
              mountPath: /var/backups
              subPath: backups
#            - name: postgres-data
#              mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
#              subPath: initScripts
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

As you can see some options under volumeMounts are commented out, that's because I was testing around. When they all are commented out the deployment works fine, when any of them isn't, I get the error.

anyways, when running `kubectl apply -f postgres-deployment.yaml...` my pod gets stuck on `CreateContainerConfigError`

Here is the events part of kubectl describe pod.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age               From               Message
  ----     ------            ----              ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  23s               default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: persistentvolumeclaim "postgres-pv-claim" not found. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..
  Warning  FailedScheduling  22s               default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..
  Normal   Scheduled         19s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/postgres-7bf8f99856-98cxl to minikube
  Normal   Pulled            6s (x4 over 19s)  kubelet            Container image "postgres:alpine" already present on machine
  Warning  Failed            6s (x4 over 19s)  kubelet            Error: stat /home/kubernetesUser/postgresKubernetes/volume: no such file or directory
```

It says... /home/kubernetesUser/postgresKubernetes/volume: no such file or directory.

I feel like maybe I'm not understanding how pv's work?

Sorry for not clarifying, the path that supposedly doesn't exist, does indeed exist in my host machine.

Comment: are you using preemptable nodes ? looks there if you notice first line PVC not found check first it's bound and PVC and PV status if proper.

Comment: I see that you are using `storageClassName: manual`. Could you check what is the output of command `kubectl get sc`? As far as I know on fresh cluster you don't have such `storageClass` so maybe `persistentVolume`  have some problems due to reference to non existing sc?

Comment: I wouldn't normally expect to see a `hostPath:` type volume; since it has no notion of which node the data is on, it means your storage can be misplaced if the pod is ever deleted and recreated on a different node.  Can you let the cluster storage provisioner create the PersistentVolume, rather than creating it yourself?  Would it make sense to use a StatefulSet to create the PersistentVolumeClaim too?

Comment: Hello @Vincent Adams, Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like the cause of your issue: Configmap that’s referenced in your pod does not exist.**

When your pod refers to a PV that is not correctly configured or when creating a pod from the manifest file, if the container referenced in the pod’s manifest file has an empty (no such file or directly).

If you want to use Hostpath volume, you should be scoped to only the required file or directory, and mounted as **ReadyOnly**.

As per the official kubernetes document on [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath):

> A `hostPath` volume mounts a file or directory from the host node's
> file system into your Pod. This is not something most Pods will need,
> but it offers a powerful escape hatch for some applications.
>
> If you're restricting HostPath access to specific directories through
> AdmissionPolicy, `volumeMounts` MUST be required to use `readOnly`
> mounts for the policy to be effective.

Also check node’s [Container Runtimes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) doesn’t clean up old containers. Try reinstalling the node’s container runtime and register again the failed node. Where is trying to assign the container ‘s pod.